# Android ADs by admob problems

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have developed application called "TV Spored ++" actual for Slovenian users. I have tested it on few devices before adding it to market. It worked well more or less on all tested devices. Today I have tried it on Galaxy tab and noticed that ads are not showing.

Switching this device to test mode fore ads `aRequest.addTestDevice(...);` actually showed test banner.

I connected to the same Wi-Fi and tried to connect with Galaxy tab and Nexus S. Nexus S showed ads and Tab didn't.

What can I do?

I only get the what is shown on image below.

[image: APP Screen]

Comment: could you post a logcat of what happens on the Galaxy Tab?

Comment: Already got response from ad provider... Something is wrong server-side...

Comment: Interesting, would you mind giving details?

Comment: They only said that they have already received complaints from other clients and that they are working to fix this issue :/ that just it